# max, min properties in topology

Tags: general-topology, continuity

I have a question on quotient topology which I just do not understand the authors explanation at all for this example, and that is:

**Example:** let $h$ be a (real-valued) continuous function on some closed interval $[c,d].$ Let, $\lambda =\min_{[c,d]}h$ and $\gamma = \max_{[c,d]}h$ . Also, $h$ can be considered as a surjective map (onto) from $[c,d] \rightarrow [\lambda,\gamma]$.

**Question** How can one show that if $[c,d]$ has the usual topology, then the quotient topology on $[\lambda,\gamma]$ is also the usual topology ?

I have been doing some examples on this topic quotient topology, but I can only find one relevant example in my notes which was determining the quotient topology on a function $f=x^2$ from the lower limit topology on $\mathbb{R}$ to $[0,\infty)$, this example I could understand, but although my concepts with open sets, and continuity are getting better, now it seems like I am stuck on trying to understand quotient topologies.

I would really appreciate some clear help to help me understand topology better.

Comment: You might need to edit this problem a bit. I'm not sure what you mean by "the quotient topology on $[\lambda,\gamma]$." I *think* you are trying to say that $h$ induces an equivalence relation on $[c,d]$ by letting $a \sim b$ if $h(a) = h(b)$. I also *think* you mean that $h$ is a *real*-valued function defined on $[c,d]$ (and that is worth saying in your question). $h$ should not be introducing any kind of topology on $[\lambda,\gamma]$ that comes to mind immediately for me.

Comment: What I mean is that $h$ can absolutely induce a quotient topology on $[c,d]$ by quotient'ing out by the equivalence relation I just described, and I *think* that's what you might be trying to ask about...

Comment: I just wrote exactly what the notes said it says $h$ is continuous on the closed and bounded interval $[c,d]$ and it exactly says if $[c,d]$ has the usual topology, then the quotient topology on $ [\lambda,\gamma]$ is the usual topology.

Comment: OK, well perhaps you should find what they mean by the quotient topology on $[\lambda,\gamma]$ then, because no such quotient topology comes to mind immediately for me. You typically can quotients of an object in a category (e.g. a topological space in the category of topological spaces) by quotient'ing out by the *preimage* of a morphism (e.g. a continuous function) rather than anything to do with the image of that morphism.

Comment: How I am learning at least through these notes are that define a quotient topology on $Y$ to be $T_{Y}=\{V\subset Y:f^{-1}(V)\in T_x\} $ where  $ f:X \rightarrow Y$, and a topological space $X$ with topology $T_X$.

Comment: OK... I've never seen that definition of a quotient topology before, and it certainly doesn't look like what I think of as a quotient. However, since $h$ is assumed to be continuous already, it seems like you can do what @Perturbative suggested easily enough.

Comment: How would I do that could you give me some hints because in the solution the author seems to really like using epsilon delta's and I dont really follow it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hint: To show two topologies are equivalent you need to show that one is a subset of another and vice versa, so that they both (as sets) are equal.

Comment: The reader may also note that the topologies themselves are sets of sets. (It can be a bit confusing.)

Comment: Ok so I tried multiple ways, but I cant seem to show that one subset is of another, vice versa, could you give me some more hints please?